# Create an image using little ones

Tags: python, image

I'm making a "Map Maker" (and no, I don't want to use one that already exist).

I have a text file containing "00011000" and 2 images : 1.png and 0.png (same size).

My idea is to assemble those 2 images as described in the text file (3 times the 0.png, then 2 times the 1.png, ...) to create an image with width = 8*width(1.png); height = 1*height(1.png).

What python function should I use to do so ?

Do I need a special library ?

Comment: Have you checked out `PIL`? Install it by installing `pillow` - solves issues with external libraries required to handle certain extensions.

Comment: your file construction limits amount of files to 10 (0-9). Try to fix it, it'll make your program more flexible

Comment: @makciook it's actually using 8bits value (so all the comon ASCII characters) but as my question is only about the lbirary/function I should use I explained my question in a simple way.

Comment: @kroolik Sadly i'm working with python 3.3 that doesn't look like supported by PIL yet

Comment: have you tried imagemagick ? it should do what you want. It is a command line utility, not a python library, but if you feel not confortable in bash scripting you can use python to call imagemagick with the right arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pillow library http://pillow.readthedocs.org/ and function paste : it works !

```
from PIL import Image
img0 = Image.open(img/test.png);
blank_image = Image.open("images/map_blank.png")
blank_image.paste(img0, (0,0))
blank_image.save("result.png")
```